# Informatica Powercenter data truncation/overflow error

Tags: unicode, overflow, informatica-powercenter, truncation

I'm trying to make a simple data loading with an IPC mapping from one Oracle DB to another.

The source table structure is following:

```
ID  NUMBER;
C_VALUE VARCHAR2 (16);
C_CODE  VARCHAR2 (16);
SN  NUMBER;
SU  NUMBER;
```

The target table structure is following:

```
ID  NUMBER
C_VALUE VARCHAR2 (20)
SSID    NUMBER
LOADID  NUMBER
LOADROWNUMBER   NUMBER
DATEBEGIN   DATE
DATEEND DATE
```

When I'm running the workflow I'm getting the following error:

> 8340||Error: Target table [TYPE_ACC_RRB] data truncation/overflow
>   error.

When I'm trying to debug my mapping, I'm seing that my input string in the `c_value` field is presented by the unicode characters and it's length is doubled in bytes.

Does the Informatica count chars of bytes as the length of it's string fields?
How to make it see for chars, not for bytes?

What I see from the session log is:

```
Server Mode: [UNICODE]
Server Code page: [UTF-8 encoding of Unicode]
The session sort order is [Binary].
Source database connection [RBO01] code page: [MS Windows Cyrillic (Slavic)]
Target database connection [STG1] code page: [MS Windows Cyrillic (Slavic)]
```

My mapping:

[image]

Comment: Pretty directly. Look at the picture

Comment: YesFirst of all my setting "Reject Truncated/Overflowed rows" in the session was turned off and I saw truncated strings in the target table. For exaple, in the source it was the value "пассивный", but in the target table i became "пассивны".

Comment: It didn't help. First I've changed    string to    nstring at the source qualifier and at the expression transformation. Runned the mapping and got the same. Then I've changed varchar2 to nvarchar2 in the target definition - still got that error. Then I've tried to run the debugger of this mapping. In the debugger I've tried to pass mt data through this mapping, and the data passed successfully without errors. But the data is displayed in the strange way - Informatica displays bytes instead of unicode characters: http://andsh.ru/mapping_debug.png

Comment: It works in the Debugger but it does not work in real. When firstly it worked without the "Reject Truncated/Overflowed rows" activated, my target table was filled with the truncated strings consisting of 8 cyrillic characters but my tables field is     Varchar2(20) and the encoding of my database is simple cl8mswin1251

Comment: Can you try inserting the data through sqlplus on the host were Informatica is installed and check if you are able to see the correct data? If not, you might have to check NLS_LANG environment variable on that box. Try setting it as the same value as the target database code page (MS windows Cyrillic (slavic)).

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to define the environment variable     NLS_LANG=russian_russia.cl8mswin1251 on the IPC server